# JSX duplicate layer Adobe Photoshop

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I have a problem with duplicating layers from one document to another. I have this code (.jsx script inside my Photoshop document)

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
app.activeDocument.selection.selectAll();

var calcWidth  = app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[2] -app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[0];

var calcHeight = app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[3] - app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[1];
var docResolution = app.activeDocument.resolution;

var document = app.documents.add(calcWidth, calcHeight, docResolution);
app.activeDocument = docRef;

try {
  dupObj.artLayers[i].duplicate(document, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
}
catch(e) {
  alert(e)
}
```

But I am still receiving an error

> Error: You can only duplicate layers from the frontmost document.

Have you any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting an error is `dupObj` is never defined. I think you mean to use `docRef`, the reference to your source document in line 1. This seems to work fine now:

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
app.activeDocument.selection.selectAll();

var calcWidth  = app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[2] -app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[0];

var calcHeight = app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[3] - app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[1];
var docResolution = app.activeDocument.resolution;

var document = app.documents.add(calcWidth, calcHeight, docResolution);
app.activeDocument = docRef;

try {
  docRef.artLayers[i].duplicate(document, ElementPlacement.INSIDE); // ** changed to docRef **
}
catch(e) {
  alert(e)
}
```

That being said there might be a few hidden bugs in there you should look at. In this line:

```
docRef.artLayers[i].duplicate(document, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
```

`i` is never defined, and apparently defaults to 0 without throwing an error. The result is you will only ever duplicate the first layer in the `artLayers` array.

Also, since you are selecting the entire document using `app.activeDocument.selection.selectAll();` there is no need to calculate the size of the selection. It will always be the same size as the original document. You could just use `docRef.width` and `docRef.height` as the width and height for the new document. Besides, when you duplicate a layer it will copy the whole layer regardless of the selection, as far as I know.

If you just want to make a new document the same size as the layer you are duplicating try using `artLayers[i].bounds` instead of `selection.bounds`

Comment: `document` is a reserved term in JS and should not be used as the variable name here - rather use something like `doc`

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the active document: You need to call a reference to the active document and the one your using - hence the error.

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
docRef.selection.selectAll();

var calcWidth  = docRef.selection.bounds[2] -app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[0];

var calcHeight = docRef.selection.bounds[3] - app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[1];
var docResolution = docRef.resolution;

var document = app.documents.add(calcWidth, calcHeight, docResolution);
app.activeDocument = docRef;

try {
  dupObj.artLayers[i].duplicate(document, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
}
catch(e) {
  alert(e)
}
```

I've not used dupObj before as I use CS and script listener code for duplicating documents
And I've not checked the code, but give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The problem is that you're trying to use a variable called `document` which is reserved in JS.</strike>

As Sergey pointed out, `document` is (amazingly) not a reserved word in JSX **because Adobe JSX is not 'regular' JSX**

Although it doesn't address the exact syntax error I'll leave this here because it's a quick way to solve the overall problem of copying layers between documents.

```js
// Grab docs
const doc1 = app.activeDocument
const doc2 = app.documents.add(100, 100)

const outputLayer = doc1.layers[0]
const inputLayer = doc2.layers[0]

inputLayer.duplicate(outputLayer, ElementPlacement.INSIDE)
```

Comment: `document` isn't a reserved word in JSX. The problem was a different thing, specified in an answer from 9 years ago...